# phpMyAdmin mysql/mariaDB group by not working

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have some data regarding trams and the stations they go to. Each tram has a colour (Blue, yellow, Purple) They arrive at the station each station at different times. I am trying to group the data so the time they arrive as a particular station will be shown in one row.

for example i have the following rows of data

```
ID    stationID     colour     time
1       11          Yellow      13:00
2       11          Blue        14:14
3       11          Purple      15:30
```

I want to group it to the following:

```
StationID     YellowTime      BlueTime      PurpleTime
11             13:00           14:14         15:30
```

I am using a case statement and a group by to do this however i am getting unexpected results.

My query is below

```
SELECT StationID,Station_name,
 (CASE
 WHEN ID=1 THEN Time 
ELSE 'Does not come to this station' END) AS YellowTime,
 (CASE WHEN ID=3 THEN Time 
ELSE 'Does not come to this station' END) AS BlueTime, 
(CASE WHEN ID=2 THEN Time 
ELSE 'Does not come to this station' END) AS PurpleTime 
FROM tram

where Station_name like '%Cathedral%' 
group by StationID
```

The results i am getting is the following

```
StationID     Station_Name   YellowTime     BlueTime    PurpleTime
11            Cathdral      Does not...      Does no..  10:57:00
```

It is only showing me the time for the last record in the dataset rather than all three of them.

P.s.The value for the purpleTime and blueTime column is does not come to this station but i have not written it out completely in order to fit it all onto one row.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Invalid group by. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: BTW, your query contains columns forgotten in the sample table data.

Comment: @jarlh i thought so too as usually i would do what you said when using a sql server database as sql server forces you to do so. However when i add station_name aswell to the group by clause i get two rows. one showing yellowtime and the other two as does not... and the second row showing purple time and the other two as does not...

Comment: @jarlh sorry this may be a dumb question but what do you mean by columns forgotten in the sample data. Do you mean columns not in the example? If so then hopefully i can explain it better. the example is just to show what i wanted from the query. The columns in the query are my real columns and are in the data.

Comment: @jarlh assuming that the data is just station ID, station_Name and Time how would i get this group by to work?

Answer (score 0):

I thought this may help anyone that comes across this. I have managed to find another wya to get my desired results. 
I am using a join to the same table instead, as the case statement wasn't working.

Here is the query i used

SELECT t.StationID,t.Station_name
ifnull(t1.Time,'Does not come to this station') as yewllowTime,
ifnull(t2.Time,'Does not come to this station') as purpleTime,
ifnull(t3.Time,'Does not come to this station') as BlueTime
FROM tram t
left join (select StationID, Time 
      from Tram 
      where ID=1) t1
      on t.StationID=t1.StationID
     left join (select StationID, Time 
      from Tram 
      where ID=2) t2 
      on t.StationID=t2.StationID
      left join (select StationID, Time 
      from Tram 
      where ID=3) t3 
      on t.StationID=t3.StationID
where station_name like '%Cathedral%'
Group by t.StationID

with this query i got 1 row with all the different times for each colour as desired.

Hope this helps someone with the same issue.